# defaultLocale_format is not a function when using D3.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, angular7

I am using D3.js for making horizontal and vertical bar charts in angular 7,  when I run code on local it runs perfectly but when I make prod build I get this error- ERROR TypeError: defaultLocale_format is not a function.
I install d3 like this - `npm install d3 --save` and `npm install  @types/d3 --save`
I am Importing file like - 
`import * as d3 from "d3"`;

using D3 version 5.14.2

I dont know what I am doing wrong here, my function like this:

I think in this function I am getting error:

[image: I think in this function I am getting error:]

I debug the prod build code here what I find: 
d3.scaleLinear function converted into linear_linear() then it goes to linearish() then e.tickFormat() then src_tickFormat() and in this src_tickFormat() its returning defaultLocale_format(o) which is undefined.

function linear_linear():

[image]

function linearish():

[image: function linearish()]

function src_tickFormat() its returning defaultLocale_format():

[image: function src_tickFormat() its returning defaultLocale_format()]

Comment: There is something wrong with your D3 source code. If you look into the [source code](https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js) for v5.14.2 the string `src_tickFormat` cannot be found in that file.

Comment: Yes I checked, there is no function like that but after prod build function names are changing `return exports.format(specifier)` gets converted into `return defaultLocale_format(0)`

Comment: Hm, I am afraid without knowing your build chain and seeing a running demo showing the issue there is not much we can do for you. Can you try to set up a **minimal** demo with the output of the prod build? Just enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @altocumulus Thanks for your help I will try to set demo with the output of prod build.